# Loading and xml file and also creating java fx ui with it

Tags: java

```
(creating ui)
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.io.File;

public class XMLJavaFXLoader {
    protected static double minWidth;
    protected  static double minHeight;
    protected static Class controller;
    protected static String stageTitle;
    protected static Scene scene;
    public XMLJavaFXLoader(String filename) throws Exception {
        Document loaded = LoadXMLDocument(filename);
        getAttributes(loaded);
        minWidth = scene.getWidth();
        minHeight = scene.getHeight();
    }
    public static void getAttributes(Document doc) throws Exception {

        XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath path = xpFactory.newXPath();

        Element stage = (Element) path.evaluate("Stage",doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        stageTitle = stage.getAttribute("title");
        String controllerName = stage.getAttribute("controller");
        controller = Class.forName(controllerName);
        Element rootElement = (Element) path.evaluate("*",stage,XPathConstants.NODE);
        Pane root;
        if(rootElement.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("vbox")){
            root = new VBox();
        }
        else root = new HBox();

        NodeList rootChildren = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*",rootElement,XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < rootChildren.getLength(); i++) {
            Element curChild = (Element) rootChildren.item(i);
            getChildren(root,curChild);
        }
        scene = new Scene(root,Double.parseDouble(stage.getAttribute("width")),Double.parseDouble(stage.getAttribute("height")));
    }
    private static void getChildren(Pane parent,Element curNode) throws Exception {
        if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Label")){
            Label newLabel = new Label(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
            parent.getChildren().add(newLabel);
        }
        else if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Textfield")){
            TextField newTextField = new TextField(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
            newTextField.setId(curNode.getAttribute("id"));
            parent.getChildren().add(newTextField);
        }
        else if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("button")){
            Button newButton = new Button(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
            newButton.setId(curNode.getAttribute("id"));
            parent.getChildren().add(newButton);
        }
        else{

            XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath path = xpFactory.newXPath();

            Pane newNode;
            if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("vbox")){
                newNode = new VBox();
            }
            else newNode = new HBox();

            NodeList rootChildren = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*",curNode,XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < rootChildren.getLength(); i++) {
                Element curChild = (Element) rootChildren.item(i);
                getChildren(newNode,curChild);
            }
            parent.getChildren().add(newNode);
        }
    }
    public static Document  LoadXMLDocument(String filename) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        File myFile = new File(filename);
        Document doc = builder.parse(myFile);
        return doc;
    }
}



import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.io.File;

public class XMLJavaFXLoader {
    protected static double minWidth;
    protected  static double minHeight;
    protected static Class controller;
    protected static String stageTitle;
    protected static Scene scene;
    public XMLJavaFXLoader(String filename) throws Exception {
        Document loaded = LoadXMLDocument(filename);
        getAttributes(loaded);
        minWidth = scene.getWidth();
        minHeight = scene.getHeight();
    }
    public static void getAttributes(Document doc) throws Exception {

        XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath path = xpFactory.newXPath();

        Element stage = (Element) path.evaluate("Stage",doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        stageTitle = stage.getAttribute("title");
        String controllerName = stage.getAttribute("controller");
        controller = Class.forName(controllerName);
        Element rootElement = (Element) path.evaluate("*",stage,XPathConstants.NODE);
        Pane root;
        if(rootElement.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("vbox")){
            root = new VBox();
        }
        else root = new HBox();

        NodeList rootChildren = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*",rootElement,XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < rootChildren.getLength(); i++) {
            Element curChild = (Element) rootChildren.item(i);
            getChildren(root,curChild);
        }
        scene = new Scene(root,Double.parseDouble(stage.getAttribute("width")),Double.parseDouble(stage.getAttribute("height")));
    }
    private static void getChildren(Pane parent,Element curNode) throws Exception {
        if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Label")){
            Label newLabel = new Label(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
            parent.getChildren().add(newLabel);
        }
        else if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Textfield")){
            TextField newTextField = new TextField(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
            newTextField.setId(curNode.getAttribute("id"));
            parent.getChildren().add(newTextField);
        }
        else if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("button")){
            Button newButton = new Button(curNode.getAttribute("text"));
            newButton.setId(curNode.getAttribute("id"));
            parent.getChildren().add(newButton);
        }
        else{

            XPathFactory xpFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath path = xpFactory.newXPath();

            Pane newNode;
            if(curNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("vbox")){
                newNode = new VBox();
            }
            else newNode = new HBox();

            NodeList rootChildren = (NodeList) path.evaluate("*",curNode,XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int i = 0; i < rootChildren.getLength(); i++) {
                Element curChild = (Element) rootChildren.item(i);
                getChildren(newNode,curChild);
            }
            parent.getChildren().add(newNode);
        }
    }
    public static Document  LoadXMLDocument(String filename) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        File myFile = new File(filename);
        Document doc = builder.parse(myFile);
        return doc;
    }
}

main class

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Creating scene and controller from XML...");
        XMLJavaFXLoader loader = new XMLJavaFXLoader("layout02.xml");

         System.out.println("Initialising stage...");
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(loader.minWidth);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(loader.minHeight);
        primaryStage.setTitle(loader.stageTitle);
        primaryStage.setScene(loader.scene);

        System.out.println("Showing stage...");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

Controller

public class Controller implements JavaFXController {
    public void btnAddClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        lblOutput.setText("btnAddClicked, X="
                + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
    }

    public void btnMultiplyClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        lblOutput.setText("btnMultiplyClicked, X="
                + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
    }

    public void btnFactorXClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        lblOutput.setText("btnFactorXClicked, X="
                + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
    }

    public void btnDiffClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        lblOutput.setText("btnDiffClicked, X="
                + txtX.getText() + ", Y=" + txtY.getText());
    }

    private Scene scene;
    private Label lblOutput;`your text`
    private TextField txtX;
    private TextField txtY;

    @Override
    public void setScene(Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
        lblOutput = (Label) scene.lookup("#lblOutput");
        txtX = (TextField) scene.lookup("#txtX");
        txtY = (TextField) scene.lookup("#txtY");
    }``
}
```

i tried doing this but it gives errors in the factors but it does not work kindly please assist on how to fix this Not inherently. This is due to the fact that reflection gives one the option to make changes to the current class in use during runtime. For instance, the accessibility of fields could be changed to public. As a result, this might distort the overall functionality of the class at hand. For instance, you could get that the private field has getter and setter methods – thus, having its accessibility changed would therefore make these methods redundant.

Comment: Are you doing this for academic reasons? Because why not just use a `javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader`?